# Позиционированный блок

Tags: javascript, css

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть блок, который скрыт на 80% и при наведении срабатывают 2 скрипта - блок "выезжает" сбоку и меняется фон страницы. Вопрос: почему,  когда я навожу курсор на область, соответствующую открытому блоку (сам он скрыт) у меня срабатывает скрипт смены фона? Проблема только в браузерах Safari & Chrome, в остальных все нормально работает.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под открытым блоком? В чем проблема? Срабатывает один скрипт или оба?

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вы разделили эти два скрипта? Сделайте одним.

Comment: ширина блока - 500, он скрыт на 80%, т.е. когда я навожу на часть блока, которая видна, он раскрывается на 100% и срабатывает 2 скрипт.
проблема в том, что когда я навожу курсор рядом с блоком, на области шириной 500, все равно срабатывает 2 скрипт

Comment: @woland учитывая ваш комментарий что позиционирование relative нужно, почитайте подробно об этом свойстве и как структура воспринимает это позиционирование! А потом возвращайтесь с вопросом и хотя бы с куском кода!

Answer (score 1):

Буквально пару часов назад, я уже приводил [один из своих примеров](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/rzfF7/1/). Гляньте, может и вам подойдёт. Кстати, насчет двух скриптов - там реализованы два действия под одним событием. Может и это пригодится.

P.S. А вообще, вам правильно сказал [[@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan)](/users/3526/palmervan), что желательно кусок своего кода показывать.